# Are entities from different contexts compatible with each other?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say the following piece of code is executed:

```
using (var e = new MyEntities())
  CurrentUser = (from u in e.users where (...) select u).SingleOrDefault();
```

When the `using` block is over, I can only access to user fields, and that's OK.

Now in some other code, in another thread, I create another instance of `MyEntities` and do another query like this:

```
using (var e = new MyEntities())
  temp = (from u in e.users where (...some other condition...).SingleOrDefault();
```

Now, is it right to do the following comparison?
`temp==CurrentUser`

I mean, we know that these two objects (`temp`,`CurrentUser`) may be referring to the same record, but what about the instances? Are they the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `CurrentUser` and `temp` are references, calling `temp == CurrentUser` only compares those references (not the actual objects) so they will never be true. If you want to compare your entities, the best thing to do is implement `IEquatable` and override `obect.Equals()` and `object.GetHashcode()`. Then you can call `temp.Equals(CurrentUser)` and that will give the desired behavior. For example:

```
public class User : IEquatable<User>
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   ...

   public bool Equals(User other)
   {
      return this.Id == other.Id;
   }

   public override bool Equals(object other)
   {
      return this.Id == (User)other.Id;
   }
   public override int GetHashcode()
   {
      return this.Id.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

Note: you should always override the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods on `object` too. For example `HashSet<T>` uses those methods internally instead of the generic version implemented by `IEquatable<T>` so if you don't override them, you will get the wrong results.

Comment: @Javid Actually, you are comparing just POCOs. It's up to you to compare them based on their primary key (simple or composed).

Comment: What about the times when we need to use `CurrentUser` in a linq that's executed in another context?

Comment: @Javid If you're doing the query in linq-to-entities, you can't pass the `CurrentUser` into your query anyways, you would always compare the Id's or other properties

Comment: You don't need to implement IEquatable<User> just override == operator from Object class.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Implementing `IEquatable<User>` allows you to use `IEqualityComparer<User>.Default()` with your own compare logic for linq queries. Also if you implement the interface it's just a sign to other people who read your code that you've provided your own compare logic.

Comment: This is a clean solution, but there's a bit of problem. Any change to the entity class is lost if I refresh the data model diagram.

Comment: Oh you're using the designer? I would just go for comparing the Id's then if I were you. Also use code first, it's much better. EF7 even got rid of the designer.

Comment: Really? That's interesting. I prefer code-first personally; but this time my tables were created before writing the code. Can I use code-first concept on this database from now on?

Comment: You can choose design from database or code first from database :) (not only in EF7, in earlier versions of EF too)